# How to interpret the conditional expected value in a regression?

Tags: regression

If you want to estimate $E[y| x = \text{some value}]$ is this just a matter of plugging $x$ into the regression equation?

Because you estimate the regression coefficients, therefore the value you get is an estimate also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is predicted value of dependent variable y give the independent variable x.
The dependent and independent variables may be scalars or vectors.